# Do Gothic preposition du “unto” and Ukrainian preposition do “to” have the same origin?

Tags: етимологія

Do Gothic preposition *du* “unto” and Ukrainian preposition *до* “to” have the same origin?

Matthew 25:40

"jah andhafjands sa þiudans qiþiþ **du** im"

"And the King shall answer and say unto them"

"Цар відповість і промовить **до** них"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, thought that's unclear.

Ukrainian *[до](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B4%D0%BE#Ukrainian)* is from Proto-Slavic *[*do](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/do)*, which is from Proto-Indo-European *[*de ~ *do](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/de)*

For Gothic  (*[du](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/du#Gothic)*), Wiktionary currently says that it's **probably related** to Proto-Germanic *[*tō](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/t%C5%8D)*, for which, on it's side, it says that it's from Proto-Indo-European **doh₁*, which is instrumental singular of the aforementioned **de ~ *do* (also Wiktionary explicitly says that Proto-Germanic **tō* is cognate of Russian *до* (which is obviously very close cognate of Ukrainian *до*)).

So, probably both are somehow derived from Proto-Indo-European **de ~ *do*.